# How to call `GetParam` method from a controller method with ResponseEntity<> return type within the same class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to call a `GetParam method` from another controller within the same `Controller class` to refresh the page after some set of operations. This is what I have tried.

```
@GetMapping("/inventories")
    public String showInventories(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("inventories", inventoriesService.getUserInventory());
        return "user_inventories";
    }

@PostMapping(value = "create_inventory_record", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createInventoryRecord(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> inventoryRecord)
        throws Exception {

        InventoryRecord newInventory = new InventoryRecord(
            0,
            inventoryRecord.getFirst("addProductType"),
            inventoryRecord.getFirst("addProductDescription"),
            inventoryRecord.getFirst("addProductCategory")
        );

        // Response HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> inventoryCreationResponse = inventoryService
            .createInventoryRecord(newInventory);
        boolean inventoryCreated = Boolean.parseBoolean(limitCreationResponse.get("ItemCreated"));
        boolean inventoryItemExists = Boolean.parseBoolean(limitCreationResponse.get("ItemAlreadyExists"));

        // Check if item created/stored
        if (!inventoryCreated) {

            // Check if item already exists
            if (!inventoryItemExists) {
                // Throw exception if Inventory didn't exist but still record wasn't created
                return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body("Inventory item not created!!");
            } else {
                // Inventory already exists, advice user on front-end
                return ResponseEntity.ok(inventoryCreationResponse);
            }
        } else {

            // Refresh inventories page
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).location(URI.create("inventories")).build();
        }
    }
```

The `showInventories(Model model)` method shows/loads the inventory when the page is loaded. I have a button within the page that shows a form to get inputs for the inventory details. I then send a POST request to the springboot controller. The data is received and the whole process succeeds i.e., the data is stored in the database, I get a response on whether the record was created, if not it will notify for existing similar record, if not throw an exception.

##### Problem

The controller that receives the data before processing is of type  `ResponseEntity<?>`, the one named `createInventoryRecord`. After checking for record creation, and if record exists, in case the record was stored successfully, I want to call the `showInventories` method with the `@GetMapping("inventories")`.

I have tried using ResponseEntity as below to try calling that path but it does not work.
My problem is.

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).location(URI.create("inventories")).build();
```

There is something I am missing, where am I going wrong, what should I do, or do better?

Answer (score 0):

try returning with `redirect:/`, like this:

`return "redirect:/inventories";`

Comment: This will not work, my return type is RequestParam<?> not String